# Not able to Launch AMIs into EC2-Classic in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Earlier we could launch our AMIs into EC2-Classic now it is forcing us to launch into vpc only. Why this restriction?

Step 3: Configure Instance Details

Network  : The dropdown value for Launch into EC2 Classic is disabled.

How can I enable ?

Comment: More details are needed. Perhaps you chose a newer instance type that is VPC only.

Comment: From EC2 Dashboard I clicked Launch instance Button, I didn't use VPC

Comment: And the first thing that it asks is the instance type you want to launch, and some of those instances types (pretty much all the newer types I think) are "VPC Only". In other words AWS doesn't support running those instance types in EC2 Classic. So if you chose one of those newer instance types then on the next screen it won't let you chose EC2 classic.

Comment: Also, new AWS customers, and existing customers using new AWS regions, do not have the option to use EC2-Classic. They must use VPC. This is indicated in the "Supported Platforms" section of the EC2 Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Instance Types Available Only in a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#vpc-only-instance-types)

> Some instance types are not available in EC2-Classic, so you must
>   launch them in a VPC. By launching an instance in a VPC, you can
>   leverage features that are not available in EC2-Classic, such as
>   enhanced networking, assigning multiple private IP addresses to the
>   instance, and changing the security groups assigned to your instance.
>   For more information, see Instance Types Available Only in a VPC.

Instances of the following instance types are **not supported in EC2-Classic** and must be launched in a VPC:

- C4
- M4
- P2
- T2
- X1

Answer (score 0):

"Most of the newer instance types require a VPC. The following are the only instance types supported in EC2-Classic:

General purpose: M1, M3, and T1

Compute optimized: C1, C3, and CC2

Memory optimized: CR1, M2, and R3

Storage optimized: D2, HS1, and I2

Accelerated computing: G2"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html#ec2-classic-instance-types